# Glimpse Security

Tags: asp.net-mvc, glimpse

I am convinced that I want to use Glimpse for my project, but I would like to learn a bit more about the security model.

From what I can tell, when you turn Glimpse on, it simply writes a set of cookies to the client. When Glimpse receives these cookies, Glimpse begins to record information for the request and then sends it to the client.

Seems like I could just set the cookies for a site I know uses Glimpse and I would then be able to see their information.

I highly doubt this is how it works, so I would like to know what features are in place to prevent exposing server information.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Glimpse uses a collection of configurable **Runtime Policies** (http://getglimpse.com/Help/Custom-Runtime-Policy) that dictate how Glimpse responds to any given HTTP request.

Glimpse already adds some Runtime Policies out of the box that filter requests based on content types, http status codes, remote or local access, Uri's...

You can also build your own by implementing the `IRuntimePolicy` and check for instance if a user is authenticated and member of a specific group and based on that allow Glimpse to gather and return data or not. Such an example can be found at the link above.

Comment: Well said @cgijbels. In addition, policies can be disabled as covered in the [Policy Management](http://getglimpse.com/Help/Configuration) section of the docs.